# Insert a new value if there is a duplicate

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table with multiple duplicates (Log in) for an id. Normally after each "log in" there must be a "log out". If yes, then I do not have to do anything. If after a "log in" there is no "log out" then I have to create one at the and of the day (23:59:59).

I have the following table:

```
  Id      Status     Date    
  A      Log in      01.01.2018  01:44:03
  A      Log out     01.01.2018  02:57:03
  C      Log in      01.01.2018  01:55:03
 ser     Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:55
 ser     Log out     03.01.2018  01:59:55
  M      Log in      04.01.2018  01:59:55
```

The table should look like this:

```
 Id      Status     Date    
 A      Log in      01.01.2018  01:44:03
 A      Log out     01.01.2018  02:57:03
 C      Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:03
 C      Log out     01.01.2018  23:59:59  
ser     Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:55
ser     Log out     03.01.2018  01:59:55
 M      Log in      04.01.2018  01:59:55
 M      Log out     04.01.2018  23:59:59
```

A formula like this

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2=A3,B2="Log in",B3="Log out"),AND(A2=A1,B2="Log Out",B1="Log in")),"Keep","You need to insert a log out")
```

could help me to see if afer a "log in" exists a "log out", however she does not help me to insert a a new line in sheet. Any idea how I can do this? Do you think I need vba?

*if there is a "log out" after a "log out" for the same id, both "log outs" will be removed

Comment: Willl your formula work, if C logs out before B?  You can use VBA, the other alternative would be to use formula to build the table you want off a "data" sheet?

Comment: Why don't you have following column headers: `Id`, `Login date`, `Logout date`?

Comment: I would recommend that you create a new table. In the old one you hold the new entries, and the new one uses Excel formulas that enumerate log in events in one column and looks up the next log out event after them into a second column, or 23:59:59 if none found. Then you can use the old table for input and the new table for output.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Actually the data is sorted and C will never be before B.

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu you may be thinking about it the wrong way, how is the data added?  Is it possible to add 2 rows instead of 1, the 2nd being the default log out time, then when adding the log out time, look for this line and change the value?

Comment: I thought about the variant to save the "good data" in another sheet. The "wrong" data, so only login, can be manipulated more easier, I just need to insert a logut after each login. For that I think I need vba. Do you think there is a simpler option?

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu 2 questions: 1. Is the date and time in one column or are the s 2 seperate columns? 2. Are these date values or strings?

Comment: @PEH 1. Date and time are in one column. 2. Dates (I think there is not a problem to convert in strings and after again in date). I will edit the post, because it can be this case: if there is a log out after a log out for the same id, both log outs will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the following data. The blue column is what we would assume the code should do:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddMissingLogoutLines()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 2 'start in row 2

    Do Until ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = vbNullString
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value = "Log in" Then 'we are in a login line …
            If ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "B").Value = "Log out" And ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "A").Value = ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value Then
                'login line followed by its logout line
                'this is what we want so we do nothing
            Else 'login line followed by a login line or a mismatching logout line
                'logout is missing add it
                ws.Rows(iRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "A").Value = ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value
                ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "B").Value = "Log out"
                ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "C").Value = DateValue(ws.Cells(iRow, "C").Value) + (1 - (1 / 24 / 60 / 60))
            End If
            iRow = iRow + 2
        Else  'we are in a logout line …
            If ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "B").Value = "Log out" Then 'logout line followed by a logout line
                'logout after logout so delete both
                ws.Range(iRow & ":" & iRow + 1).Delete
            Else 'everything is ok go to next line
                iRow = iRow + 1
                'if you want to remove single `log out` lines with no login line too, then replace the iRow = iRow + 1 above with ws.Rows(iRow).Delete here
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

After the code is run we see that 2 `Log out` lines were deleted and the 2 missing `Log out` lines that were missing for the `Log in` lines were created.

[image]

Comment: Works, however there can happen this: "A" starts with log out and for id "A" there is only this value. Or what if there is an id "X" that contains 3 log out consecutiv times? ( There will remove only 1 log out)

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu your example data didn't show these cases so these cases are not covered by my code. You can only get what you ask for, also this answer is already much more than what you could have expected (this is no free coding service). This is the answer to what was asked in your question, and should give you a good idea what the techniques are to do such data validation. • So instead of asking us to do all the work for you, start working yourself now that you've got a good starting point.

Comment: @PEH Thanks, sorry, it's more then enogh for a good starting point. Thx

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu I've made an edit. Have a look at the very last `Else` statment there is a comment. It will probably solve the issue already.

Comment: Thx, very helpful

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu: Please have a look at the update of my answer regarding the possible errors you mentioned (starts with log out, three consecutive log outs).

Comment: @z32a7ul my comment in the last `Else` statement already fixed that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I think your code does not work in the following situation (while mine does): A logs in, B logs in, C logs in, C logs out, B logs out, A logs out. You would insert a log out after the first "A logs in" row because your code checks only the first row after the log in, and not the later ones. In a multi-user system, however, users can log in and out while others are logged in.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I don't agree with your solution. Log out before log in should be considered an overnight session needing a log in event at midnight, three consecutive log outs without a log in from the same user should be considered an error (not to be hidden by the program), three consecutive log outs from different users is, however business as usual, and is not handled correctly by your code.

Comment: @z32a7ul The OP said the data is sorted by ID first so this cannot happen. That's why I took the shortcut. Sorted data is much easier to handle and we don't need to care about this case.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Sorry, I didn't see that comment.

Comment: @z32a7ul No worries ;) it is in the comments below the question: *"Actually the data is sorted and C will never be before B"*

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBA for this:

```
Option Explicit

' Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime

' dctIds
'   Id => dctSessions
'           LogIn => dctSession
'                      "Id" => String
'                      "LogIn" => Date
'                      "LogOut" => Date

Public Sub ExtendData()
    Dim dctIds As Dictionary: Set dctIds = New Dictionary
    ReadData dctIds, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
    WriteData_v1 dctIds, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output_v1")
    WriteData_v2 dctIds, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output_v2")
End Sub

Private Sub ReadData(dctIds As Dictionary, ewsInput As Worksheet)
    ' Assumption: header in first row, data starts in second row
    Dim r As Long: For r = 2 To ewsInput.UsedRange.Row + ewsInput.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        ' Assumption: Id is in first column
        Dim strId As String: strId = ewsInput.Cells(r, 1).Value
        ' Assumption: Status is in second column
        Dim strStatus As String: strStatus = ewsInput.Cells(r, 2).Value
        ' Assumption: Date is in third column, and ms precision is enough, change data type to Double and use Value2 instead of Value otherwise
        Dim datDate As Date: datDate = ewsInput.Cells(r, 3).Value

        Dim dctSessions As Dictionary
        If dctIds.Exists(strId) = False Then
            Set dctSessions = New Dictionary
            dctIds.Add strId, dctSessions
        Else
            Set dctSessions = dctIds(strId)
        End If

        If strStatus = "Log in" Then
            Dim dctSessionNew As Dictionary: Set dctSessionNew = New Dictionary
            dctSessionNew.Add "Id", strId
            dctSessionNew.Add "Status", strStatus
            dctSessionNew.Add "LogIn", datDate
            dctSessions.Add datDate, dctSessionNew
        ElseIf strStatus = "Log out" Then
            Dim dctSessionLast As Dictionary: Set dctSessionLast = Nothing
            Dim varSessionFound As Variant: For Each varSessionFound In dctSessions.Items
                Dim dctSessionFound As Dictionary: Set dctSessionFound = varSessionFound
                If dctSessionLast Is Nothing Then
                    Set dctSessionLast = dctSessionFound
                ElseIf dctSessionLast("LogIn") <= dctSessionFound("LogIn") Then
                    Set dctSessionLast = dctSessionFound
                End If
            Next varSessionFound
            If Not dctSessionLast Is Nothing Then
                dctSessionLast.Add "LogOut", datDate
            Else
'                Debug.Print "No Log in before Log out in row " & r
                Dim dctSessionOvernight As Dictionary: Set dctSessionOvernight = New Dictionary
                dctSessionOvernight.Add "Id", strId
                dctSessionOvernight.Add "Status", strStatus
                dctSessionOvernight.Add "LogIn", DateValue(datDate) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)
                dctSessionOvernight.Add "LogOut", datDate
                dctSessions.Add dctSessionOvernight("LogIn"), dctSessionOvernight

            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Invalid Status in row " & r
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Private Sub WriteData_v1(dctIds As Dictionary, ewsOutput As Worksheet)
    ' Assumption: header in first row, data starts in second row
    Dim r As Long: r = 2
    Dim varSessions As Variant: For Each varSessions In dctIds.Items
        Dim dctSessions As Dictionary: Set dctSessions = varSessions
        Dim varSession As Variant: For Each varSession In dctSessions.Items
            Dim dctSession As Dictionary: Set dctSession = varSession
            ' Assumption: Id is in first column
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 1).Value = dctSession("Id")
            ' Assumption: Status is in second column
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 2).Value = dctSession("Status")
            ' Assumption: Date is in third column, and ms precision is enough, change data type to Double and use Value2 instead of Value otherwise
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 3).Value = dctSession("LogIn")
            r = r + 1
            ' Assumption: Id is in first column
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 1).Value = dctSession("Id")
            ' Assumption: Status is in second column
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 2).Value = dctSession("Status")
            ' Assumption: Date is in third column, and ms precision is enough, change data type to Double and use Value2 instead of Value otherwise
            With ewsOutput.Cells(r, 3)
                If dctSessions.Exists("LogOut") Then
                    .Value = dctSession("LogOut")
                Else
                    .Value = DateValue(dctSession("LogIn")) + TimeSerial(23, 59, 59)
                End If
            End With
            r = r + 1
        Next varSession
    Next varSessions
End Sub


Private Sub WriteData_v2(dctIds As Dictionary, ewsOutput As Worksheet)
    ' Assumption: header in first row, data starts in second row
    Dim r As Long: r = 2
    Dim varSessions As Variant: For Each varSessions In dctIds.Items
        Dim dctSessions As Dictionary: Set dctSessions = varSessions
        Dim varSession As Variant: For Each varSession In dctSessions.Items
            Dim dctSession As Dictionary: Set dctSession = varSession
            ' Assumption: Id is in first column
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 1).Value = dctSession("Id")
            ' Assumption: Status is in second column
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 2).Value = dctSession("Status")
            ' Assumption: LogIn is in third column, and ms precision is enough, change data type to Double and use Value2 instead of Value otherwise
            ewsOutput.Cells(r, 3).Value = dctSession("LogIn")
            ' Assumption: LogOut is in fourth column, and ms precision is enough, change data type to Double and use Value2 instead of Value otherwise
            With ewsOutput.Cells(r, 4)
                If dctSessions.Exists("LogOut") Then
                    .Value = dctSession("LogOut")
                Else
                    .Value = DateValue(dctSession("LogIn")) + TimeSerial(23, 59, 59)
                End If
            End With
            r = r + 1
        Next varSession
    Next varSessions
End Sub
```

As you can see, my macro can create to outputs:

v1: The way you asked for: the original rows + additional rows to close sessions at the end of the day

v2: The table format recommended by me and others: each session is a row with two dates (log in and log out), where the second date is the end of the day, if missing from the original table

It will look like this after running the macro:

[image: Log In and Out Picture]

Note: The header (Id, Status, etc.) was not created by the macro but manually.

**Update:**

Having read the OP's comments to PEH's solution, I modified the error handling code ("No Log in before Log out in row x").

This way, the code will also enter log in dates if it finds log out dates. This is useful because if you allow overnight sessions, it's not enough to close log in events that will end the next day but you should also open the sessions that were started the day before.

Sessions that last several days are still not managed by this code (it would require to analyse the logs of all days).

Regarding the three consecutive log outs: this should be considered an error, and should not be hidden by a program code because it requires further investigation (Why did it happen?).

Comment: Thanks! Actually it is more than I need. Thx